# How to Flip a string in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, sequence, textjoin

I have this google sheets input column on the left, I want to flip the string like shown in the output column.

```
Input   Output
--------------
bats    stab
live    evil
meet    teem
part    trap
stop    pots
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string to it's characters using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) delimiter, then `REDUCE` the string  using `current&accumulator`(reversal happens here):

```
=REDUCE(,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,,""),""),LAMBDA(a,c,c&a))
```

For a array, use `BYROW`:

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(str,REDUCE(,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(str,,""),""),LAMBDA(a,c,c&a))))
```

Comment: [](https://i.imgur.com/MsLY3JL.png)

Comment: @Osm Fixed. ⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: I liked how the [pow steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73854304/how-to-flip-a-string-in-google-sheets/73858789?noredirect=1#comment130421917_73858789) leading to the formula

Comment: Format it to apear fully at first glance, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857564/19529694), or [this](https://i.imgur.com/fMg025f.png) typo(sort) add a short breakdown,

Comment: @Osm I think this depends on device width of the end user. My first formula  should be completely visible in most devices. The second formula only adds a prefix with `BYROW` and `INDEX/COUNTA`. I don't think splitting up is necessary in this case. Furthermore, split up formula cannot be copy pasted directly in a cell.

Comment: I'll try to use `REDUCE` more often.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula, just replace `A2:A` range with yours.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",
              BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(range, 
              TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,MID(range,SEQUENCE(LEN(range),1,LEN(range),-1),1))))))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`MID`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129) - [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) - [**`LEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A1:A, LAMBDA(x, JOIN(, 
 INDEX(MID(x, LEN(x)-SEQUENCE(1, LEN(x))+1, 1))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A1:A, LAMBDA(x, JOIN(, 
 INDEX(MID(x, LEN(x)-SEQUENCE(1, LEN(x))+1, 1))))))
```

[image]

or:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A1:A, LAMBDA(x, JOIN(, INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(""&x, 
 REPT("(.)", LEN(x)), "$"&LEN(x)-SEQUENCE(1, LEN(x), )))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Put the second one first, didn't think of it before.

Comment: I not overlooking `IFERROR` again.